# Why won't sort work

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I write the following program to sort vector of struct by time after read in and process certain info, but it won't work and give me error message:

> ```
> `no matching function for call to ‘swap(collisionOfCars&, collisionOfCars&)’`,`error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct
> std::enable_if<false, void>’` and `error: use of deleted function
> ‘collisionOfCars& collisionOfCars::operator=(collisionOfCars&&)’
> *(__first + __holeIndex) = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(__first + __secondChild));`
> ```

My guess is sort function has some issues, but I do not know how to fix it.
Here is my code;

```
  class Car{
 public:
    string ID;
    double xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel;
    bool collided;
    Car(){

    }
    Car(string ID, double xPos, double yPos, double xVel, double yVel, bool collided){
      this->ID = ID;
      this->xPos = xPos;
      this->yPos = yPos;
      this->xVel = xVel;
      this->yVel = yVel;
      this->collided = collided;
    }
};
struct collisionOfCars{
 public:
  Car &firstCar;
  Car &secondCar;
  double time;
};
bool tupleCompare(collisionOfCars first, collisionOfCars second) {
  return first.time < second.time;
}
collisionOfCars willCollide(Car &car1, Car &car2) {
   double posDifX = car1.xPos - car2.xPos;
   double posDifY = car1.yPos - car2.yPos;
   double velDifX = car1.xVel - car2.xVel;
   double velDifY = car1.yVel - car2.yVel;

   double a = velDifX*velDifX + velDifY*velDifY;
   double b = posDifX*velDifX+posDifY*velDifY;
   double c = posDifX*posDifX + posDifY*posDifY - 100;
   double possibleSol = b*b - a*c;     // b^2-4ac

  double sol1, sol2;
  if ((a == 0) || possibleSol < 0) {     // check for a = 0 or b^2-4ac < 0
    return collisionOfCars{car1, car2, -1};
  } else if (possibleSol == 0) {
    sol1 = -b/(2*a);
    if(sol1 >= 0){
      return collisionOfCars{car1, car2, sol1};
    }
  } else {
    sol1 = (-b + sqrt(possibleSol))/(a);
    sol2 = (-b - sqrt(possibleSol))/(a);
    if (sol1 <= sol2 && sol1 >= 0) {
      return collisionOfCars{car1, car2, sol1};
    } else if (sol2 <= sol1 && sol2 >= 0) {
      return collisionOfCars{car1, car2, sol2};
    } else {
      return collisionOfCars{car1, car2, -1};
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  vector< Car > collection;     // All info of cars
  vector< collisionOfCars > collision;      // all possible collision
  string ID;
  double xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel;
  while (cin >> ID >> xPos >> yPos >> xVel >> yVel) {
    collection.push_back(Car(ID, xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, false));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < collection.size(); j++) {
      collisionOfCars result = willCollide(collection[i], collection[j]);
      if (result.time != -1) {
        collision.push_back(result);
      }
    }
  }
  sort(collision.begin(), collision.end(), tupleCompare); // where goes wrong
}
```

In case you are wondering, I use reference in struct to make sure any change to Car pass in to struct will reflect on vector< Car > collection

---

I have changed the reference to pointer but now it gives me new error message as following

```
cannot convert ‘Car’ to ‘Car*’ in initialization
       return collisionOfCars{car1, car2, sol1};
```

Comment: where does it give the error?

Comment: Show us the definition of `tupleCompare`

Comment: `collisionOfCars` is not trivially assignable because it contains reference members, which cannot be reseated. This means that `std::sort()` is *unable to swap `collisionOfCars` instances* around, which is required to sort the vector. Consider using pointers in this struct instead of references.

Comment: The error does not appear till I add sort() to my code

Comment: Try writing your own operator= for that class. You can't do it. Neither can the compiler. Use pointers instead.

Comment: Or there are very complicated solutions involving proxy arrays of pointers or indexes which get sorted and then create a new sorted array by copying the original items in sorted order. But you'd only do that if you really HAD to.

Comment: I must say that even though C++ error messages have improved immensely over the last 10-20 years, the error given here is still terrible and probably very difficult to understand for anyone who isn't an expert in C++.

Comment: There are 2 things to try when error messages are too confusing for you.  The easiest is to try compiling your code, unchanged, with clang++ (i.e. simply replace your current use of g++ with clang++, you have it installed, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `std::sort()` to work, `std::swap()` must be instantiated for the type of object being sorted (`collisionOfCars`). In order for this to happen, it must either be copy- or move-assignable (or have an `std::swap()` specialization).  Your type does not declare either operator, and the compiler is not generating one for you because your type does not meet the requirements to have the operator generated.

This is because the type has non-static data members of a reference type. (Keep in mind that references *cannot* be reseated, so it's impossible to swap two references such that they refer to different objects -- you can only swap the content of the referred-to objects, which is not what you want.)

> A defaulted copy assignment operator for class T is defined as *deleted* if any of the following is true:
>
> ...
>
> - T has a non-static data member of a reference type;

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move assignment operator for class T is defined as *deleted* if any of the following is true:
>
> ...
>
> - T has a non-static data member of a reference type;

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)

This means that `collisionOfCars` instances *cannot be assigned on top of each other* and this is *required* to sort the vector.  (How else can the vector be sorted if not by swapping elements around on top of each other?)

The simplest solution would be to change `collisionOfCars` to use `Car *` (pointer-to-`Car`) instead of `Car &` (reference-to-`Car`).  You could also use [`std::reference_wrapper<Car>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) (which is just a wrapper around a pointer anyway).

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan The error is likely because you have to now treat it as a pointer everywhere. E.g. you have to change `collisionOfCars{car1, car2, sol1}` to `collisionOfCars{&car1, &car2, sol1}`, etc.